# Usage of Coil inside accompanist HorizontalPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I need to create a `HorizontalPager` with images from server.

I'm using `Coil 2.2.2` and everything is fine when I open the app a second time (because of the cache). But when I open the app for the first time (or after clearing the cache), the download speed is extremely slow, for example the **2MB** image takes **5 seconds** to load, sometimes it can be **up to 12 seconds**
I thought this was due to a lot of recomposition counts inside the `HorizontalPager` when I switch page, so I try to add coil `ImageRequest` to the `context.imageLoader` queue. But even if I don't swith the page image loading extremely slow

How I can make image loading faster?

Here is my code

```kotlin
                ConstraintLayout {
                    val (pager, indicator) = createRefs()

                    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
                    val loadedData = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, ImageRequest>() }

                    HorizontalPager(
                        count = banners.size,
                        state = pagerState,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(height)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = AppTheme.dimensions.padding_20, start = AppTheme.dimensions.padding_16, end = AppTheme.dimensions.padding_16)
                            .background(AppTheme.colors.placeholderBackground, shape = AppShapes.medium)
                            .constrainAs(pager) {
                                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                                linkTo(start = parent.start, end = parent.end)
                            }
                            .clip(AppShapes.medium)
                    ) { page ->
                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            if (loadedData[page] == null) {
                                with(density) {
                                    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                                        .data(banners[page].bannerUrl)
                                        .size(
                                            width = boxWithConstraintsScope.maxWidth.roundToPx() - horizontalPaddingsDp.roundToPx(),
                                            height = height.roundToPx()
                                        )
                                        .crossfade(true)
                                        .build()

                                    context.imageLoader.enqueue(request)
                                    loadedData[page] = request
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        val request = loadedData[page]

                        AsyncImage(
                            model = request,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                        )
                    }
```

Comment: Is image loading is slow in only HorizontalPager or it happens every places?

Comment: only in the HorizontalPager

Comment: Hmm . Thats quite weird . I try to reproduce this. And find a solution.

Comment: thank you so much, I have no ideas how to fix it

Comment: @GowthamKK hi, so do you have any news?(

Comment: No luck in finding the solution.Trying